# Sorting Issue with ActiveRecord relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a strange sorting issue with my models.

Given the following:

- I have a model called Cv, which has many occupations and skills, and is linked to a country.
- I also have a model called Vacancy, which has one occupation and many skills, and is also linked to a country.

In my controller, I have the following lines of code:

```
@occupations = Occupation.find params[:occupation_ids].split(' ')
@skills = Skill.find params[:skill_ids].split(' ')
@cv = Cv.find params[:cv_id]
@language = Language.resolve({:code => :en, :name => :en})
@vacancies = Vacancy.joins(:vacancy_skills).where('vacancy_skills.skill_id' => params[:skill_ids]).all.uniq.sort{ |x,y| (x.skills | @skills).length <=> (y.skills | @skills).length }
```

The idea is that all vacancies are beeing sorted by their relevance, which is calculated by the length of the union between the selected skills (`@skils`) and the skills of the vacancy in question.

When I run the code, I receive all vacancies, ordered by country and sorted by relevance, but I don't want them ordered by country, instead I want them all mixed but **sorted by relevance**.

The current output is :

- vacancy 1, 100% relevance, united kingdom
- vacancy 2, 90% relevance, united kingdom
- vacancy 3, 10% relevance, united kingdom
- vacancy 4, 90% relevance, france
- vacancy 5, 70% relevance, fance

The desired output should be like this:

- vacancy 1, 100% relevance, united kingdom
- vacancy 2, 90% relevance, united kingdom
- vacancy 4, 90% relevance, france
- vacancy 5, 70% relevance, france
- vacancy 3, 10% relevance, united kingdom

What am I supposed to change/do to get it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in the sort algorithm.
I used the | operator instead of the & operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to troubleshoot this in the console. You're almost certainly getting something you don't expect in @skills or _.skills (where _ is x or y). Get your set of vacancies into a variable in the console and then dig deeper into what you're seeing.

```
v = Vacancy.joins(:vacancy_skills).where('vacancy_skills.skill_id' => params[:skill_ids]).all.uniq
puts v.each {|vv| puts "#{vv.id}\t#{vv.skills.inspect}" }
```

See if it shows you anything you didn't expect to see. From your "current output" example it appears to me that perhaps the sort is basing it's order on the length of some string vs the length of an array or enumerable.